# Laravel composer autoload/ guzzlehttp : fatal error

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, autoload

When deploying my Laravel website (1&1 mutualized), this is the fatal error I get:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/41/d623699018/htdocs/athyr/athyr - copie/athyrcopie/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.0') in /homepages/41/d623699018/htdocs/athyr/athyr - copie/athyrcopie/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

I already tried `composer update` & `composer dump_autoload`. And I checked that it's PHP 7 everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
php artisan optimize
```